# Force run of a task skipped by ShortCircuitOperator

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that uses `ShortCircuitOperator` to skip downstream tasks that are (usually) unnecessary. In a few exceptional circumstances, I would like to still run these downstream tasks, and would prefer not to have to modify my DAG to deal with every possible case. Is there a simple way in the Airflow UI or via console to force the run of downstream tasks after they've been skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here, you can manually clear the state of the task instances via the UI, but you have to clear the state of downstream tasks. I was running into issues because I wanted to skip part of the DAG and was trying to clear the state of tasks further downstream, which was of course causing them to immediately be set to skipped again. If you really want to skip a part of a DAG this way, you can do it, you just need manually to set the dependencies immediately upstream of the tasks you want to run to succeeded.